# WP7: EntitySet loading. One to many relation - composite primary key case

Tags: windows-phone-7, database-design, relational-database, windows-phone-7.1, entity-relationship

I'm creating application for Windows Phone and faced with a problem related to database handling.
A part of designed database (approximately) looks like:
two tables
USER { ID } - ID is a primary key
ACCOUNT {ID, OWNERID, BALANCE} - ID and OWNERID - is a composite primary key, that means the ID of user's account is unique only in scope of the user.

Composite primary key in the last table was intended to be used, because account.ID is supposed to be defined by user and there is quite high possibility that several users define accounts with the same identification.

So in C# it looks like the next:

```
[Table]
public class User
{
    [Column(IsVersion = true)]
    private Binary _version;

    public User()
    {
        _accountsRef = new EntitySet<Account>(OnAccountAdded, OnAccountRemoved);
    }

    private string _id;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = false, CanBeNull = false, Storage = "_id")]
    public string ID { 
        get { return _id; } 
        set
        {
            if(string.Equals(value, ID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                return;
            RaisePropertyChanging("ID");
            _id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
        } 
    }

    private EntitySet<Account> _accountsRef;

    public EntitySet<Account> Accounts
    {
        get { return _accountsRef; }
    } 

    private void OnAccountAdded(Account account)
    {
        account.Owner = this;
    }

    private void OnAccountRemoved(Account account)
    {
        account.Owner = null;
    }

    ....
}

[Table]
public class Account : PropertyChangingNotificator
{
    [Column(IsVersion = true)]
    private Binary _version;

    private string _ownerId;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    public string OWNER_ID
    {
        get { return _ownerId; } 
        set
        {
            if (value == OWNER_ID)
                return;
            RaisePropertyChanging("OWNER_ID");
            _ownerId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("OWNER_ID");
        }
    }

    private EntityRef<User> _ownerRef;
    [Association(Name = "FK_USER_ACCOUNTS", ThisKey = "OWNER_ID", OtherKey = "ID", Storage = "_ownerRef", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public User Owner { 
        get { return _ownerRef.Entity; }
        set 
        { 
            User previousValue = _ownerRef.Entity;
            if(previousValue==value)// && !_ownerRef.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
            {
                return;
            }
            if(previousValue!=null)
            {
                _ownerRef.Entity = null;
                previousValue.Accounts.Remove(this);
            }
            RaisePropertyChanging("Owner");
            _ownerRef.Entity = value;
            if(value!=null)
            {
                value.Accounts.Add(this);
                OWNER_ID = value.ID;
            }
            else
            {
                OWNER_ID = string.Empty;
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("Owner");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the query which asks for accounts of user with give id:

```
var accounts = from a in dataContext.Accounts
               where a.OWNER_ID == userName
               select a;
List<Account> accoutsList = accounts.ToList();
```

In a result I get correct list of accounts each item of which has appropriate User object as Owner property.

But in case I'm trying to get user object from datacontext like this:

```
var user = (from u in dataContext.Users
              where u.ID.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()
              select u).
                        SingleOrDefault();

property user.Accounts has EntitySet without loaded values (also even after call user.Accounts.Load();)
```

In debug watch Accounts entity set has next properties values:

```
   HasAssignedValues         == false;
   HasLoadedOrAssignedValues == false;
   HasLoadedValues           == false;
   HasSource                 == false;
   HasValues                 == true;
   IsDeffered                == false;
   IsLoaded                  == false;
```

Due to content here: **[Windows Phone Mango Local Database(SQL CE): [Association] attribute](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-SQL-CE--Association-attribute)**
i also have to mark Accounts property with **[Association(Name = "FK_USER_ACCOUNTS")]** attribute to let datacontext to know that it is related to association **FK_USER_ACCOUNTS.**
But if I set ThisKey = "**ID**", OtherKey = "**OWNER_ID**" in this association - I get an exception during database creation, which tells that the whole primary kay (**ACCOUNT.ID and ACCOUNT.OWNERID**) should be a part of association, but not only part of primary key (which is ACCOUNT.ID). If it was possible to add such association on User side - I guess, problem would be solved.

Can anyone of you suggest how to get User entity with loaded Accounts entity set?
Thanks in advance.
Dmytro.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .Include(). Like:

```
var user = (from u in dataContext.Users.Include("Accounts")
          where u.ID.ToUpper() == userName.ToUpper()
          select u).
                    SingleOrDefault();
```